# PC running Ubuntu 18.04 automatically restarts right after shutdown

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, battery, restart, charging

I have ASUS X550LD with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed. Problem is my PC starts automatically right after shut down. To fix the issue I visited couple of threads. One solution I found is disabling the `Wake on LAN` setting from BIOS, but I could not find that in my BIOS settings. There was a `wake on lid` option which I disabled.

Now when the laptop is not charging and is on battery it doesn't automatically start after shut down, but when the laptop is charging, the issue is still happening.

I had this issue before when I had Windows installed on my laptop, but that time it was a hardware issue and I [fixed it by replacing the power button](https://superuser.com/a/1254834/191162). Now the same problem is unexpected because if the hardware issue had persisted, it wouldn't have worked when laptop is not charging state i.e. on battery.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @starkus No there is no such option.